# Remove folder from being tracked with `git`, but do not delete that folder from filesystem when performing `git pull` on another host

Tags: git

I removed a folder from being tracked with `git` with the following command:

```
git rm -r --cached path_to_your_folder/
```

After that I put the path into my `.gitignore` and did an `git commit`. I expected that `path_to_your_folder` will be left untouched on another host, after I did a `git pull`, but the complete folder was removed from the file system. How can I prevent that and keep the folder on the file system of the host which is performing the `git pull`?

Comment: This is a tricky problem.  The best pattern really to follow with Git is that files/folders should either be completely tracked or completely untracked, but not both.

Comment: I thought that `git rm -r --cached path_to_your_folder/` will completely untrack the folder (as you mentioned) - I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The thing is, you've now told Git to basically remove this folder.  So, it's doing that.

Comment: I got you. I thought I was just telling `git` to forget about that folder, remove it from the repository and not take care of it anymore (according to this, not to delete it from filesystem).

Comment: OK, but I think what Git is doing is that it sees the old folder there, then realizes that you have some earlier commit which removed it.  It thinks the local branch is behind, and then goes ahead and removes it again.  Hence, best to keep things tracked as tracked, and vice-versa for untracked.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible, I've tried to find anything that could help, but failed. So I decided to see if there is anything that could simulate the desired behavior, and I did find something, so I posted this workaround as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything that fits perfectly using only flags or another command, but after some research I've found a workaround to restore it even after the deletion from the `git pull`.

It uses a few commands as shown below:

```
git pull && git checkout <last-commit-with-folder> path_to_your_folder/ && git reset
```

This works, but it's not pretty.

First it does the `git pull`, then it restores the file or folder from git history with `git checkout` and then removes the addition to git's index, due to checkout's behavior, with `git reset`, leaving the repository just as if nothing were deleted.

If the **last commit with folder** is the previous one then you can use this:

```
git pull && git checkout HEAD^ path_to_your_folder/ ** git reset
```